# Xamarin forms could not connect to logcat

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, logcat

I stumbled upon this error: Couldn't connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned: 0

I tried everything I found online , restarting adb, Shared Run Time, Enable ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and INTERNET, rebuilding project, restoring packages and deleting bin and obj folders. Any other suggestions?

Comment: First of all, Which kind of  android device(Android Emulator or other Android device) that used? Use andriod emulator to make a test. Please update your VS to the latest version, then click repair in the VS installer. and uninstall your application  in your emulator. Make a test again, if this issue is still existed.